# How to do push segue through a button from one view controller to another?

Tags: objective-c, segue

I'm new to Objective C and I've been trying to do Segue using a button from one view controller to another. I wish to use a push type for the segue with which, the first view controller is embedded in a navigation view controller. Below is the .m and .h files of the first view controller.

*firstViewController.m*

```
@implementation

**(am I supposed to have an IBAction here for the pressed button?)**

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstSegue"]) {

    **( I don't know what to put here)**    

    }
}
@end
```

*firstViewController.h*

```
@interface firstViewController : UIViewController



@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have wired up the button itself to the segue (ctrl + drag from the button to the second view controller in the interface builder), then you will not need an IBAction. As long as your view controller is properly associated with a navigation controller, just wiring up the segue in this way should be sufficient to do a push animation from the first view controller to the second--you won't have to write any code at all.

The purpose of the `prepareForSegue` method is pass data to the target view controller, set up a delegate, etc. If you have no data to pass to the second view controller, or nothing to configure in that controller, then you wouldn't need to implement `prepareForSegue`. You can search online for terms such as storyboard segue delegate to find some tutrorials [like this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) that describe some best practices for using `prepareForSegue` and other storyboard functionality to manage transitions between your view controllers.

Comment: I tried to do what you've suggested. So, I made one view controller named firstViewController. After dragging the new view controller (2nd view controller) to the storyboard, I created a new file, an objective C class named secondViewController, of type UIViewController. Then I identified this view controller's class name to be secondViewController. After setting up these view controllers, I wired up a button from the firstViewController to the secondViewController. Lastly, I clicked the firstViewController and embedded the Navigation View Controller. 

The compiler ran successfully yet,

Comment: I got this one line highlighted which is from the main.m file


" return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DiscountWalletAppDelegate class])); "

along with that highlight is a marker which says: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: This showed up after I clicked on the button on my simulator.

Comment: Yo! figured this one out already. I've successfully done segue. But then, my secondViewController doesn't show it's contents (label, text field). Basically, it shows me a black screen with a back button on its upper left hand corner.